# python mocking sqlalchemy connection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mocking, python-mock

I have a simple function that connects to a DB and fetches some data.

```
db.py

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool


def _create_engine(app):
    impac_engine = create_engine(
        app['DB'],
        poolclass=NullPool  # this setting enables NOT to use Pooling, preventing from timeout issues.
    )
    return impac_engine


def get_all_pos(app):
    engine = _create_engine(app)
    qry = """SELECT DISTINCT id, name FROM p_t ORDER BY name ASC"""
    try:
        cursor = engine.execute(qry)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        return rows
    except Exception as re:
        raise re
```

I'm trying to write some test cases by mocking this connection -

tests.py

```
import unittest
from db import get_all_pos
from unittest.mock import patch
from unittest.mock import Mock


class TestPosition(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('db.sqlalchemy')
    def test_get_all_pos(self, mock_sqlalchemy):
        mock_sqlalchemy.create_engine = Mock()
        get_all_pos({'DB': 'test'})




if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run the above file python tests.py, I get the following error -

```
   "Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string '%s'" % name
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'test'
```

Shouldn't mock_sqlalchemy.create_engine = Mock() give me a mock object and bypass the URL check.

---

Comment: can you elaborate on what the desired assertion is? the test currently has no assertions in it. also you need to mock _specific_ modules inside `sqlalchemy` not the whole library itself so your problem appears to be two-fold

Comment: This should be my assertion - mock_requests.create_engine.cursor.fetch_all.assert_called_once()...Should I mock sqlalchemy object and then mock each and every method separately ie; mock_sqlalchemy.create_engine.return_value = mock_engine

Comment: yes you will have to create the objects that implement the methods that your `engine` does like `execute`.

Comment: Your function doesn't use `db.sql_alchemy.create_engine`; it uses `db.create_engine`; that's what you need to mock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option would be to mock your `_create_engine` function. Since this is a unit test and we want to test `get_all_pos` we shouldn't need to rely on the behavior of `_create_engine`, so we can just patch that like so.

```
import unittest
import db
from unittest.mock import patch


class TestPosition(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch.object(db, '_create_engine')
    def test_get_all_pos(self, mock_sqlalchemy):
        args = {'DB': 'test'}
        db.get_all_pos(args)
        mock_sqlalchemy.assert_called_once()
        mock_sqlalchemy.assert_called_with({'DB': 'test'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

If you want to test certain results you will need to properly set all the corresponding attributes. I would recommend not chaining it into one call so that it is more readable as shown below.

```
import unittest
import db
from unittest.mock import patch
from unittest.mock import Mock


class Cursor:
    def __init__(self, vals):
        self.vals = vals

    def fetchall(self):
        return self.vals


class TestPosition(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch.object(db, '_create_engine')
    def test_get_all_pos(self, mock_sqlalchemy):
        to_test = [1, 2, 3]

        mock_cursor = Mock()
        cursor_attrs = {'fetchall.return_value': to_test}
        mock_cursor.configure_mock(**cursor_attrs)

        mock_execute = Mock()
        engine_attrs = {'execute.return_value': mock_cursor}
        mock_execute.configure_mock(**engine_attrs)

        mock_sqlalchemy.return_value = mock_execute

        args = {'DB': 'test'}
        rows = db.get_all_pos(args)

        mock_sqlalchemy.assert_called_once()
        mock_sqlalchemy.assert_called_with({'DB': 'test'})
        self.assertEqual(to_test, rows)
```

Comment: no problem, however this test doesn't really test the outcome of `get_all_pos` so I would suggest implementing behavior for `execute` and `fetchall` that way you can check your two logic branches (`try/except`)

Comment: @user1050619 check the update, it should provide what you are looking for, you should add a test to test for the exception branch as well